# XSLT: Find max Effdt, but exclude any date that is greater than today

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Looking for some help/guidance on syntax and best way to do this.

This code finds the max Effdt out of three dates - I'm good to go with that part.
Problem: Some Effdts may be future dated dates, which I do not want to consider when finding and returning the max Effdt.
How can I say:
Find max Effdt out of the three dates, but exclude any date that is greater than today.

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-date(max((xs:date(ws:Info/ws:Effdt1), xs:date(ws:Info/ws:Effdt2), xs:date(ws:Info/ws:Effdt3) )), '[Y0001][M01][D01]') "/>
```

For example, say the xslt returns these three dates:
20190401
20190424
20190430

I want to find the max Effdt that is not past today so would expect results of: 20190424

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `current-date` function and a predicate: `max((ws:Info/ws:Effdt1, ws:Info/ws:Effdt2, ws:Info/ws:Effdt3)/xs:date(.)[. lt current-date()])`. Or probably greater than today would be `. le current-date()`.

Comment: Great, that works!  But how do I add the format date back in now?  It has to be in format yyyymmdd. Thanks!

Comment: Wrap what I have posted into your `format-date` call.

Comment: Ah, got it! I was missing the end parenthesis.  I knew it was something simple like that, but I'm so unsure about the syntax and how to piece everything together, I always worry that I'm not on the right track.  Thank you very much for your help and patience :)